# Endless loop when rewriting to https

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ssl-certificate

I recently bought a wildcard ssl certificate to move my site to https.
Since Apache can't handle multiple Virtual hosts, under the same IP, in separate s, I was forced to use VirtualDocumentRoot from mod_vhost_alias. This at first solved my problems with Apache and the wildcard certificate, but it was not for long.

For a matter of necessity, I decided to move the homepage of my site to the root of the domain (ie, http://domain.com, instead of http://www.domain.com). Once I moved, the rules I established to move to https cause an endless loop on the server, resulting in an error 500. Note that the same rules when applied to any sub-domain still works, rewriting any http to https.

The error:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.
```

My VirtualHost config:

```
<VirtualHost IP:443>
   ...
   VirtualDocumentRoot /.../public_html/%1/
   ...
   VirtualScriptAlias /.../public_html/%1/cgi-bin/
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

My .htaccess config:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]

<FilesMatch "\\.(js|css)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
```

My application was build using the Zend Framework.

The main mystery here is why does it work with any sub-domain, but does not when I'm using the root sub-domain. Any hint in what can be causing the problem? Is there any way I can see all the rewrites de .htacess does?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
```

Changes:

- *www.domain.com* and *domain.com* could be matched in one line, so did it
- check for `HTTPS` instead of `SERVER_PORT`
- redirect to HTTPT on same domain name as requested (change if you want all to point to one name).
- instead of making a rule that would "kill" rewriting, with 3 RewriteCond's in OR, negated the cond's to apply to the real rule in question
- there is no point of setting `NC` flag when matching `.*`

The rest of the `.htaccess` should stay the same (did not include those parts).